# How to restore an Activity along with its ListFragment (with data loaded from server)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listfragment

I am sure **`save-restore'** have been discussed a lot but I couldn't grasp it yet. I have following scenario

**`Launch app -->MainActivity-->onCreate() -->Loads MyListFragment`**

MyListFragment gets data from server and in onListItemClick I am launching another activity. When user comes back (by clicking Up in ActionBar) to MainActivity, everything gets recreated including MyListFragment. Also it connects again to server to get data again.

I want to avoid data reloading from server and see user the same screen with Fragment and data in it.

Appreciate any help.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to seperate the service call from the UI. There isn't a way to preserve any arbitrary number of items across the activity being destroyed and re-created.

Use a service to load the data from the server. The service should populate a local SQLite database.

Then have your listview populate the data from the SQLite database.

Comment: Thanks Greg! It looks very tedius. I have many fragments in App all of them loads data from server. Isn't there any simpler way?

Comment: Also, I checked when I launch another activity from the MyListFragment in MainActivity, MainActivity's stops (onStop()) - not destroyed. Same is true for MyListFragment. There should be some way to preserve data in adapter?

Comment: If your activity is only stopped/started I am suprised the listview requeries all data but that may well be the case. Even so, be aware that at some point the OS will destroy your activity when it is in the background. It will happen to your users. Since you have to handle that case anyway, you should probably just code the whole solution for it.